# Azure CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync() Failing with 409 (conflict

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have a method that will merge files into one file but encounter an intermittent 409 (conflict) issue when calling CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync()

Please see issue.

```
One or more errors occurred. (System.AggregateException)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at AMCS.DataExchange.Core.FileSystem.FileStorage.Implementation.AzureFileStorageService.ConsolidateFilesStreamUpload(String filesDirectory, String outputDirectory, String filename, Int32 uploadByteSize, Int64 byteReadLength)

=== Caused by ===

The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException)

   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StorageAsyncResult`1.End() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\StorageAsyncResult.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.EndPutBlock(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 1708
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 115

=== Caused by ===

The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. (System.Net.WebException)

   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<PutBlockImpl>b__57(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 2458
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 299
```

This is my code.

```
public async Task UploadStreamToOneFileAsync_new(string byBatchDirectory, string AzureStorageConnectionKey, string finalDirectory)
        {
            // track the current block number as the code iterates through the file
            int blockNumber = 0;
            int bytesRead;

            // Create list to track blockIds, it will be needed after the loop
            List<string> blockList = new List<string>();

            var containerWithDirectory = CreateContainerWithDirectoryIfNotExists(byBatchDirectory, AzureStorageConnectionKey);
            CloudBlobContainer inputContainer = containerWithDirectory.Item1;
            CloudBlobDirectory mydirectory = containerWithDirectory.Item2;

            var blockBlobs = inputContainer.GetDirectoryReference(mydirectory.Prefix).ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>();

            string filename = $"batch-combined-new.txt";
            CloudBlockBlob outputContainerBlob = GetBlobReference(finalDirectory, filename, AzureStorageConnectionKey);

            int blobCounter = 0;
            foreach (var blob in blockBlobs.OrderBy(x => x.Properties.LastModified))
            {
                blobCounter++;
                bytesRead = 0;

                var fullInputFilePath = inputContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);

                using (var mystream = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    fullInputFilePath.DownloadToStreamAsync(mystream).Wait(); // getting the file content into stream.

                    // adding New line to the stream so that next file stream will be appended to the new line.
                    if (blobCounter < blockBlobs.Count())
                    {
                        byte[] newline = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
                        mystream.Write(newline, 0, newline.Length);
                    }

                    mystream.Position = 0; //reset position to 0 to get all the value of the stream
                    int size = 100000; // byte size of chuck/block of the stream.
                    
                    do
                    {
                        // create buffer and retrieve chunk
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                        bytesRead = await mystream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, size);

                        if (bytesRead != 0)
                        {
                            // increment block number by 1 each iteration
                            blockNumber++;

                            // set block ID as a string and convert it to Base64 which is the required format
                            string blockId = $"{blockNumber:0000000}";
                            string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));

                            // Upload buffer chunk to Azure
                            await outputContainerBlob.PutBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead), null);

                            // add the current blockId into our list
                            blockList.Add(base64BlockId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Reached last page. bytesRead: {bytesRead}");
                            break;
                        }
                        // While bytesRead == size it means there is more data left to read and process
                    } while (bytesRead == size);
                }
            }

            // add the blockList to the Azure which allows the resource to stick together the chunks
            await outputContainerBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockList);
        }
```

I observe that the issue happens when my code calls the method the second time within split second. Like the first call was completed and then the second call happened immediately.

Comment: *I observe that the issue happens when my code calls the method the second time* => can you post how the function is called?

Comment: `fullInputFilePath.DownloadToStreamAsync(mystream).Wait();`, probably not related to the problem by why not use `await` here instead of the blocking `.Wait()`?

Answer (score 0):

The error 409 (conflict) issue you mentioned may be related to concurrency or conflicts when multiple requests are trying to update the same blob simultaneously, especially if you have multiple calls happening very close in time.

***Firstly, I uploaded three files to my storage account container as below,***

**Blob-1** :

[image]

**Blob-2** :

[image]

**Blob-3** :

[image]

***Then, I tried the below code and was able to get the data from other blobs in the storage account container to the uploaded blob at Azure Portal.***

Code :

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

namespace AzureBlobUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "<connec_string>";
            string containerName = "<container_name>";
            string outputBlobName = "<blob_name.txt>";

            await CombineBlobsAsync(connectionString, containerName, outputBlobName);
            Console.WriteLine("Combination Blob uploaded successfully.");
        }

        public static async Task CombineBlobsAsync(string connectionString, string containerName, string outputBlobName)
        {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlockBlobClient outputBlob = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(outputBlobName);

            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            StringBuilder combinedContent = new StringBuilder();

            await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                BlobClient sourceBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await sourceBlobClient.DownloadAsync();
                    await blobDownloadInfo.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, encoding))
                    {
                        string blobContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        combinedContent.Append(blobContent);
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var combinedStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(combinedContent.ToString())))
            {
                await outputBlob.UploadAsync(combinedStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully as below:

[image]

***The blob uploaded successfully to my storage account, and it stored the other blobs data at Azure Portal as below.***

[image]